# Can MPI_Bcast correctly while using multiple threads?

Tags: mpi, openmp, openmpi

When I use the MPI, there are multiple threads doing MPI_Bcast. Like

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
  MPI_Bcast(&a[i], 1, MPI_INT32_T, TargetRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

If the data size and type are the same, it seems they will broadcast to the wrong places.
How could I fix it? (Now I use a my_bcast with Tag)
[Problem Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXRxT.png)

Comment: you cannot invoke multiple collective operations simultaneously **on the same communicator**

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you have some advice for me? I want different threads do collective operations simultaneously, and I have to split to different communicator. Actually I want to collective operations on all nodes. So how could the communication be defined?

Comment: as long as there is no simultaneous collective operation **on the same communicator** you should be fine. So either use more communicators (one per thread for example) or rework your algorithm. In this trivial snippet, a single `MPI_Bcast()` with `count=k` is likely to be faster than multiple (even if parallel) broadcasts.